# Emit - how to include library in self-contained exe-file

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I found the following code at [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570?pgno=5) (slightly rewritten):

```
namespace TestEXEApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName();
            an.Name = "TestEXEApp";
            AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyBuilder ab = ad.DefineDynamicAssembly(an,
                AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

            ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(an.Name, "Hello.exe");

            TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("TestEXEApp.Program",
                TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

            MethodBuilder fb = tb.DefineMethod("Main",
                MethodAttributes.Public |
                MethodAttributes.Static,
                typeof(int), new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });

            ILGenerator ilg = fb.GetILGenerator();
            ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, World!");

            ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(TestClasses.Class1).GetMethod("Test",
                new Type[] { typeof(string) }));

            ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
            ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Seal the lid on this type
            Type t = tb.CreateType();
            // Set the entrypoint (thereby declaring it an EXE)
            ab.SetEntryPoint(fb, PEFileKinds.ConsoleApplication);

            // Save it
            ab.Save("Hello.exe");

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

Also, I have the following class in a separate project called TestClasses:

```
namespace TestClasses
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Test(String t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test: " + t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I compile this, I get (obviously) the two files "TestEXEApp.exe" and "TestClasses.dll". If I run it, I get a new file, "Hello.exe", and if I run this new file, it prints "Test: Hello, World!". So far, so good. Now, the problem is, this new file obviously depends on TestClasses.dll. So if I emit it into another directory, or move it for some reason, it can no longer execute.

Is there some way for Reflection.Emit to in some way include the TestClasses.Class1 code into the Hello.exe executable, so that it becomes 100% self-contained (apart from the dependence on the .NET framework, obviously)? Or, if that can't be done, how can I get the program to output a copy of TestClasses.dll, so that I always have the dll-file written in the same directory as Hello.exe?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`ILMerge`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) for that?

Comment: Yes, looks like that's a good option. However, I still need the dll file. Obviously, I do have the dll-file, since I was able to run TestEXEApp.exe, but I would like (as mentioned in my last question) to have it output together with Hello.exe, which is typically not in the same folder as my executables. So basically, it boils down to: How can I figure out what dll-files are needed, and where these dll files are (so TestEXEApp.exe can copy them to the output directory)?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: Eh... what are you trying to do? This really sounds like XY problem.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. What I'm trying to do is reduce a logistic problem I'm having: I have this code that emits some new code (it's a machine learning research project), and I may need to use the emitted code later. However, my source code changes a lot, so the dll in question are also changed a lot. Therefore, I need to store all the binaries, including dlls, together with the emitted code. Otherwise I will not be able to run it later. So I need to copy the dll, therefore I was just looking for a way to avoid having to explicitly copy them each time my system is run.